# What's the difference between shader editor and compositor

Tags: shaders, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

I started learning blender about a year ago and I started learning nodes this month. Does anybody know what is the difference between the `Shader Editor` and the `Compositor`? I've seen tutorials about using the shader editor and sometimes the compositor but I mostly use the shader editor. I currently don't understand what the compositor is used for.

thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: Hello :). All editors are explained in the Blender manual: [Blender Manual - Compositing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shader editor is for editing backgrounds and materials, and it has a large viewport so you can see what you're doing. Compositor is for compositing, or combining images, and this requires more nodes (most of the time), hence the larger node area

Answer (score 0):

I came here for the answer, but I will contribute what I think it is.

Shading acts over a 3d space (2d u,v mapping to 3d) before rendering. Here are 3d effects, like displacement and bump. material lighting (which requires 3d calculations for shadows, reflections, etc...)

Compositing is post-production rendered processing, it is over image format (2d pixels) like png. Here are image processing like filters.

I could be wrong, but this is my impression.